# Session sometimes not persisting in Capybara Selenium test

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have a number of `remote: true` forms in my Rails 4 application to make up a wizard.

At each `post`, the action adds keys to the `session` object in my controller.

```
#post :some_action
 def some_action
   current_form_indetifier = params[:current_form_indetifier]
   session[current_form_indetifier] = 'some_data'
 end
```

This works fine in development and production.

It also SOMETIMES works perfectly in my Capybara Selenium test.

```
#step 1
fill_in 'My name is', with: 'Andy Smith'
fill_in 'I work at', with: 'Coca Cola'

find('.signup-form-next-button').click

#session key set in this post

wait_for_ajax

#step 2
fill_in 'Your Email', with: 'andy@smith.com'
fill_in 'Password', with: 'some-super-long-password'
find('.signup-form-next-button').click

#session key from last request is gone :-(

wait_for_ajax
```

It's super important to note that this *does* work sometimes.

However, for the majority (70%) of the time it does not working during testing.

By logging, I can see that the key/values are being added to the session in each request, but then in the next request the key is no longer in the session.

```
  #first request
  puts session.keys => "['form_1']"

  #second request
  puts session.keys => "[]"
```

Again, this works *sometimes*.

### What I've tried so far to no avail:

- enabling `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = true` in `environments/test.rb` (it's false by default)
- commenting out `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in the `application_controller.rb`

It's important to remember that this does **sometimes** work.

Any ideas?

## Update

For now I've worked around this by using the ActiveRecord SessionStore, so it seems the issue is around the cookies.

Comment: Show your test code, if you're not waiting for the responses to arrive correctly the updated cookie will never get set in the browser

Comment: thanks Tom. updated. Hmm.. it's an Ajax call... I do wait for ajax to return. Actually that can't be it, since the form had to load before I can fill it in. By the time the 2nd step is submitted the session is gone.

Comment: So the way cookie store works is that the response to the first ajax request should set an updated session cookie in the browser which should then be sent by the second request -  If it's losing the values then it means the cookie is not being updated after the first request and before the second request.  The usual reason for it not working in testing is that the second request is occurring before the first request has fully finished and been processed by the browser - that can be verified by sleeping for 5 seconds after each button click

Comment: Another possible reason is you're making requests to both localhost and 127.0.0.1 - which means cookies get set for different domain names, but if that was the case I wouldn't expect it to work sometimes